# Do I need Lock on process-shared variable when reassigning? (not incrementing)

Tags: python, concurrency, locking, python-multiprocessing

I have multiple python(3.8.10) processes forked from main. They from time to time need to change the global variables in `globvars.py`. I know I would need a lock for incrementing e.g. Value() with ctype-int, because incrementing is not atomic.

Assigning is said to be atomic, so I would assume no Lock is needed. However I am not sure what does the `LOAD_CONST(None)` do or whether `STORE_ATTR(value)` can break the atomicity.

**I want to ask if **only reassigning** shared Value is fine without Lock - it is bit expensive**
[image]

**vs**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Read and write operations automatically take the lock for the duration of the operation. That's how `multiprocessing.Value` guarantees process-safety for those operations. You don't need to take the lock explicitly. (If it could guarantee process-safety without taking the lock, there wouldn't be a lock in the first place. If you specify `lock=False` when creating a Value, reads and writes will be unprotected, and you will have to do your own locking.)

You *do* still need to take the lock explicitly for an increment. An increment isn't a read or a write - it's a sequence of operations, including both a read *and* a write, and those operations being individually protected doesn't mean the combined sequence of operations is safe.

---

The `LOAD_CONST` and `STORE_ATTR` are nothing to worry about.

The `LOAD_CONST` has nothing to do with any operations on the Value. The compiled code block just implicitly returns `None`, and the `LOAD_CONST` is loading that `None`. (This is an implementation detail - in terms of language semantics, only functions have return values.)

The `STORE_ATTR` is the bytecode for issuing a store to the `value` attribute. That sounds like some kind of low-level basic operation, but it's really not - it's more like a function call. It invokes the `Value` class's logic for taking the lock and writing to the underlying ctypes object. (At implementation level, `Value` implements this with a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) object to define how to get and set `value`, and `property` works through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors).)

Comment: wait, so when I leave the `lock=True` , I don't need to lock it even when incrementing? Because documentation states otherwise.[mp.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)
I think that (R)Lock will just get inited but not auto-deployed for operations.

Comment: @JanJanáček: You'll need to take the lock for that. The read operation is automatically protected, and the write operation is automatically protected, but that doesn't mean the combined sequence of operations is protected.

Comment: Now sorry for being silly, but for clarification... 
So re-assigning a `Value` is pure write operation, therefore I do not need to acquire a lock(when `Value(lock=True)`) - because these simple ops are auto-protected via lock. But if I were to set `lock=False` then even this re-assigning wouldn't be safe? 
I mean  how can this atomic operation get messed up when it is only write op? Is it when there would be two procs trying to write at exactly same time? That would still leave me with one of the new vals in worst case right? Bcs probability of this in my app is low - mbe zero.